Return period of vine copula
In the formula for "OR" joint return period of 3-dimensional copula modeling, we need to find C(u,v,w) but when we model using vine, we are only able to obtain the copula C(uv|w). So, how to find C(u,v,w) when we model our data using vine copula which only provide the C(u,v|w) on the second tree. And how does it apply to 4-dimensional of vine copula. Is there any R package that can be use to calculate the return period of 3-dimensional and 4-dimensional vine copula? I was wondering if you could provide some insights or guidance on this matter.

You need to read more about the vine copula construction, and the theory behind it. Then, you can easily use VineCopula package. Hope this helps.

Dear Dr. Alenezi, thank you for your suggestions. I have tried to find joint CDF for 4-dimensional copula using rvinecopulib package, and pvinecop() function. However, I am unable to find the 3-dimensional joint CDF as I need it to calculate the "AND" joint return period for 4-dimensional case. Can you give suggestion on how to find the 3-dimensional joint CDF using R when I model my data using 4-dimensional vine copula.
